# K fold cross validation in R

Tags: r, neural-network, cross-validation

As I know, the k fold cross validation is to partition the training dataset into k equal subsets and each subset is different. The R code for k-fold validation which is from R-bloggers is attached below. This data have 506 obs. and 14 variables. According to the code, they used 10 folds. **My question is that if each fold has the different subset or has some repeated data points in each fold.** I wanna make sure to test each data points without repeating, so my goal is to get each fold has different data points.

```
set.seed(450)
cv.error <- NULL
k <- 10

library(plyr) 
pbar <- create_progress_bar('text')
pbar$init(k)

for(i in 1:k){
index <- sample(1:nrow(data),round(0.9*nrow(data)))
train.cv <- scaled[index,]
test.cv <- scaled[-index,]

nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train.cv,hidden=c(5,2),linear.output=T)

pr.nn <- compute(nn,test.cv[,1:13])
pr.nn <- pr.nn$net.result*(max(data$medv)-min(data$medv))+min(data$medv)

test.cv.r <- (test.cv$medv)*(max(data$medv)-min(data$medv))+min(data$medv)

cv.error[i] <- sum((test.cv.r - pr.nn)^2)/nrow(test.cv)

pbar$step()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can shuffle the whole population from outside of the loop.
the following code might give you an idea to solve the problem.

```
set.seed(450)
cv.error <- NULL
k <- 10

library(plyr) 
pbar <- create_progress_bar('text')
pbar$init(k)

total_index<-sample(1:nrows(data),nrows(data)) 
    ## shuffle the whole index of samples

for(i in 1:k){
index<-total_index[(i*(k-1)+1):(i*(k-1)+k)] 
    ## pick the k samples from (i*(k-1)+1) to (i*(k-1)+k).
    ## so you can avoid of picking overlapping data point in other validation set
train.cv <- scaled[-index,] ## pick the samples not in the index(-validation)
test.cv <- scaled[index,]  ## pick the k samples for validation.

nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train.cv,hidden=c(5,2),linear.output=T)

pr.nn <- compute(nn,test.cv[,1:13])
pr.nn <- pr.nn$net.result*(max(data$medv)-min(data$medv))+min(data$medv)

test.cv.r <- (test.cv$medv)*(max(data$medv)-min(data$medv))+min(data$medv)

cv.error[i] <- sum((test.cv.r - pr.nn)^2)/nrow(test.cv)

pbar$step()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want to make sure i=k, right? And If I want to do Leave-one-out cross-validation, do I just change the value of k to 506?

Comment: Shuffling the samples? You would also need to shuffle the outcome variable. I also don't see the advantage over simply assigning the folds up-front. EDIT: My second point is debatable, not much of a criticism. Sorry

Comment: @aocall yeah, outcomes should be shuffled in the same way. I thought that the question asks the way to avoid sample overlaps in validation sets.

Answer (score 0):

That is not K-fold cross validation; with each fold, a new random sample is chosen, rather than assigning the samples into K folds up front and then cycling through, assigning each fold the test set in turn.

```
set.seed(450)
cv.error <- NULL
k <- 10

library(plyr) 
pbar <- create_progress_bar('text')
pbar$init(k)

## Assign samples to K folds initially
index <- sample(letters[seq_len(k)], nrow(data), replace=TRUE)
for(i in seq_len(k)) {
    ## Make all samples assigned current letter the test set
    test_ind <- index == letters[[k]]
    test.cv <- scaled[test_ind, ]
    ## All other samples are assigned to the training set
    train.cv <- scaled[!test_ind, ]

    ## It is bad practice to use T instead of TRUE, 
    ## since T is not a reserved variable, and can be overwritten
    nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train.cv,hidden=c(5,2),linear.output=TRUE)

    pr.nn <- compute(nn,test.cv[,1:13])
    pr.nn <- pr.nn$net.result*(max(data$medv)-min(data$medv))+min(data$medv)

    test.cv.r <- (test.cv$medv) * (max(data$medv) - min(data$medv)) + min(data$medv)

    cv.error[i] <- sum((test.cv.r - pr.nn) ^ 2) / nrow(test.cv)

    pbar$step()
}
```

Then, to produce error estimates with less variance, I would repeat this process multiple times and visualise the distribution of cross-validation error across repeated assays. I think you would be better off using a package which accomplishes tasks like this for you, such as the excellent [caret](https://github.com/topepo/caret).